# Need help to fine tune SQL inner join query - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need help to fine tune below Oracle SQL query, which is running for long hours.

```
 SELECT 
     MIN( E.MKT_PRC),
     MAX( E.MKT_PRC)
 FROM 
     GL_VESTINGPRIME_RPT VP 
     INNER JOIN GRANTZ G 
         ON G.GRANT_NUM = VP.GRANT_NUM 
         OR G.XFER_ORIG = VP.GRANT_NUM 
     INNER JOIN EXERCISE E 
         ON E.GRANT_NUM = G.GRANT_NUM
 WHERE 
     VP.RUNTIME_ID = :B4 
     AND VP.PLAN_NUM = NVL(:B3, VP.PLAN_NUM) 
     AND E.EXER_DT BETWEEN :B2 + 1 
     AND :B1
```

Comment: You need to give more details like table structure, data size etc.

Comment: EXERCISE table record count - 55086, GRANTZ table record count - 79180, GL_VESTINGPRIME_RPT is a temporary table.d

Comment: I am not able to place the complete table structure becoz it is exceeding the characters to place here, I could not see the attachment option here. Please let me know in breif what exact info required in table structure(like PK, FK, Index columnnames...). Please reply.

Comment: can you show the EXPLAIN PLAN output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the "or" in the join condition.  This tends to be optimized very poorly.

This version does an explicit union of the two results:

```
SELECT MIN( E.MKT_PRC), MAX( E.MKT_PRC)
from ((select E.MKT_PRC, E.MKT_PRC
       FROM GL_VESTINGPRIME_RPT VP INNER JOIN GRANTZ G 
            ON G.GRANT_NUM = VP.GRANT_NUM OR
            EXERCISE E
            ON E.GRANT_NUM = G.GRANT_NUM
       WHERE VP.RUNTIME_ID = :B4 AND
             VP.PLAN_NUM = NVL(:B3, VP.PLAN_NUM) AND
             E.EXER_DT BETWEEN :B2 + 1 AND :B1
     ) union all
     (select E.MKT_PRC, E.MKT_PRC
       FROM GL_VESTINGPRIME_RPT VP INNER JOIN GRANTZ G 
            ON G.XFER_ORIG = VP.GRANT_NUM OR
            EXERCISE E
            ON E.GRANT_NUM = G.GRANT_NUM
       WHERE VP.RUNTIME_ID = :B4 AND
             VP.PLAN_NUM = NVL(:B3, VP.PLAN_NUM) AND
             E.EXER_DT BETWEEN :B2 + 1 AND :B1
     )) t
```

If you have appropriate indexes on your tables, this should be pretty fast.